# Format a Decimal to Currency

Tags: c#, formatting, currency

I have a list of decimals that I want to be able to format as U.S. currency. I know I can do this with string.format but if I convert the decimals to a string they no long sort properly

```
1234.98
91234.12
541234.12
```

When converted to currency using string.format they will sort in this order

```
$91,234.12
$541,234.12
$1,234.98
```

I want them to stay as decimals so they sort correctly as

```
$541,234.12
$91,234.12
$1,234.98
```

Comment: Could you sort them then convert to the right string format?

Comment: so you want to sort by the value of the greatest digit in each individual number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep them as decimals within the list or container you are using to sort, and simply use string format on them when displaying. I don't understand the need have them as both a string and a decimal at the same time when you can display it anyway you wish.

Answer (score 2):

I see two main options for you here. The first is to zero-pad your numbers (`$001,234.98`) which seems like it would directly oppose most user's preferred experiences.

Another option could be to create a type for currency:

```
public class Currency : IComparable
{
    public decimal Value { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Currency b)
    {
        return Value.CompareTo(b.Value);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString("C");
    }
}
```

You'd want to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, of course. This would display sorted as expected (control properties permitting), but it would also display as expected. You might want to make the class into an immutable `struct`, of course, too. But this is just meant to show the gist.

A class like this would also provide very good LINQ support, in that you could have an `IEnumerable<T>` and simply call `OrderBy(c => c)`. You could even print out the values on lines by calling `string.Join(Environment.NewLine, coll.OrderBy(c => c))`, which is very clean.

Of course, a class like this should only be used for UI code. You wouldn't want to deal with serializing it or anything like that, since it'd provide unnecessary overhead.

Comment: I think this is the best solution.

Comment: -1. Am I missing something? (I've had a bad day so far!) String-ified and formatted numbers are not guaranteed to sort properly. I respectfully disagree with the `Currency` class. Not OO - the number collection and it's formatting should be encapsulated into one class. As is you're asking the client to instantiate the number "list", instantiate `Currency`, declare the formatting, and invent code to make it all work together.

Comment: @radarbob it really all depends on how you're using the code. I presented this as a self-contained solution wherein the class would `ToString` as expected, *and* sort as expected, each using built-in .NET utilities. There are times when a LINQ solution would be more ideal, and there are times when this would. It really just depends on the circumstances.

Comment: With respect, I'm not saying this is "not the best", etc. It is wrong. We can go to the forum if @Ironside24 wants to get into detail, but he's decided on an answer already.

Answer (score -1):

Create a class that holds the decimal and its appropriate formatted string.
Use Linq to sort the class objects by the decimal.